# Let $f(x) = 2x^2 + nx - 6$ and $g(x) = mx^2 + 2x - 4$? The functions are combined to form the new functions $h(x) = f(x) - g(x)$.

Tags: calculus, functions

Points $(2, 4)$ and $(-3, 17)$ are given to satisfy the new function. Determine the values of $m$ and $n$.

I know these formulas but I don't know what is $m$ and $n$ values are.

$$h(x)=(2-m)(x^2)+(n-2)(x)-2$$

$$h(2)=4=(2-m)(2^2)+(n-2)(2)-2$$

$$h(-3)=17=(2-m)(-3^2)+(n-2)(-3)-2$$

Help, please.

Comment: you almost have done, two-equation and two variables...is here.

Comment: Yeah but the values for m and n are so confusing and complicated. I'm not sure if they are right.

Comment: @VIVID either your arithmetic or mine is wrong.  Normally I'd assume mine because I'm prone to errors and typos but.. I did it multiply times....

Comment: @fleablood - Yeah, it seems I went wrong somewhere :)

Comment: I went wrong the first three times (didnt distribute; the the -2 disappear off the face of the earth). I always make arithmetic errors.

Answer (score 2):

Just continue... But be careful of arithmetic

$h(x) = f(x) - g(x) = (2-m)x^2 + (n-2)x -2$

$h(2) = 4(2-m) + 2(n-2)-2 = -4m + 2n +2 = 4$.

so simplify  $-4m + 2n = 2$ and $-2m + n = 1$

$h(-3) = 9(2-m)-3(n-2) -2 = -9m -3n+22 = 17$

so simplify $-9m -3n = -5$ so $3m +n = \frac 53$

Now just solve for $n$ and $m$.

Simple substitution $n = 2m + 1$ and so $3m + 2m+1 = \frac 53$ so

$5m = \frac 23$ and $m = \frac 2{15}$

ANd $n = 2\cdot\frac 2{15} + 1 = \frac {19}{15}$

Let's verify as I've seen answers all over the map.

$f(x) = 2x^2 +\frac {19}{15}x -6$ so $f(2)= 8+\frac {38}{15}-6 = 4\frac 8{15}$. and $f(-3) = 18-\frac {19}5-6=12-3\frac 45= 8\frac 15$.

Ahd $h(x) = \frac 2{15}x^2 +2x -4$ so $g(2) = \frac 8{15}+4+4=\frac 8{15}$ and $g(-3)=\frac {18}{15}-6-4= -10+1\frac 15= -8\frac 45$.

And $h(2)=4\frac 8{15}-\frac 8{15} = 4$. And $h(-3) = 8\frac 15 - (-8\frac 45)=17$.

Hmmm.... what do you know.  My arithmetic was correct and everyone else's was wrong.

That's got to be a first.

Comment: +1 for the justification :)